# Father and mother are to parents what brother and sister are to which gender neutral noun?

Tags: single-word-requests, gender-neutral

Looking for a word that denotes both brothers and sisters without gender connotations (gender neutral), in a similar fashion as parents for father and mother.

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: probably not a lot.  (pretty low-hangin' fruit.)

Comment: 'Siblings' is fully gender-neutral.

Comment: The question worded as it is now, almost nullifies the answer written by de Bernardy. He does not suggest any gender neutral alternatives to *siblings*

Comment: @Mari-LouA restored original question; glad with answer; thanks a lot for the helpful/clarifying comments.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for one of **siblings** (as in brothers and sisters), **offspring**, or **children** (as in sons and daughters).

[**Sibling**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sibling) (OED):

> Each of two or more children or offspring having one or both parents in common; a brother or sister.

Possibly [**sib**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sib) (OED):

> chiefly Zoology A brother or sister; a sibling.

Comment: +1 for sibling/s, which is the only answer necessary, imo. You wouldn't really need anything for only/single children other than he/she has no siblings, would you?

Comment: @choster: To me, siblings are about *my* siblings. When you ask someone without any about her siblings, the answer is "no siblings". I'm unaware of any terms that would denote *myself plus my siblings* (while excluding the parents).

Comment: Good answer, however it is required by the site that if you reproduce information from another source that you cite that source. See here for some examples http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/5196/71783

Comment: @Frank: The source is the built-in OS X dictionary (Right-click / Look up).

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy OS X uses New Oxford American; the easiest source is http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sib which is pretty close to what you have there.

Comment: I think it would be OK to just edit your answer to include the source as 'OS/X Dictionary'. Many people cite sites like etymonline.com which is not the source of the actual content, so it should be OK. Please also see http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6695/is-unattributed-material-being-deleted-on-sight it would be a shame to lose such a highly upvoted answer for want of a citation.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, the answer *siblings* seems to be the most terse yet adequate way to express this phrase. Here are my reasons:

1. Siblings denote *live, closely related beings*. However, there is a glitch! Mother and father are not genetically related, while brother and sister denote genetic relationship. Possibly a more accurate, yet less popular, answer might be *family members*.
2. Connotatively, a better descriptive sentence might be “*Aunt and uncle* are to *family* as *brother and sister* are to *siblings*”. Or “*Mother and father* are to *family* as *brother and sister-in-law* are to *marriage*”.

Comment: +1 again for siblings and a better discussion of it, but wasn't the OPs mention of parents/father/mother just to give an example of the gender-neutral kind of word that is being sought? I just have a hard time understanding why "siblings" isn't the one and only answer here?

Comment: Family members could have different meanings in different geographical regions, because it depends on ones definition of family. Siblings, on the other hand, can only mean brothers or sisters (or brothers and sisters). Also, there is no genetic requirement for siblings. For example, after an adoption, or after a second marriage, people who are not genetically related could still be described as siblings.

Comment: I don’t understand the second point here at all. Connotatively, “_parents_ is to _father and mother_ as _siblings_ is to _brother and sister_” is perfect. Your aunt-and-uncle example makes no sense at all. “_Aunt and uncle_ are to _family_ as _brother and sister(-in-law)_ are to ***family***” would make more sense, but completely defeat the purpose. And _mother and father_ are to ***marriage*** what _brother and sister-in-law_ are to _marriage_. Also, siblings don’t necessary denote _live_ beings. If your sibling dies, (s)he doesn’t stop being your sibling.